# Allowing a web api's e.g. GET request handler to accept either a jwt with roles or scopes

Tags: azure, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-api-management, azure-appservice

Scenario:
I have a web api coded in C#. The controller's base class is 'ControllerBase'. The web api works as a app service in Azure. But what I'm trying to do is configure an API Management to use send-request policy to gain access to the api by using a token that is requested as grant type "client credentials". This is for allowing the api to be tested in API Management's test section.

But the use of the test section is only half of the scenario. The other half is to call the API Management from the SPA application by using 'authorization code' grant type. And I have managed to get only the other use case working. By calling the API by using a token with 'client credentials' grant type. Currently trying to access the API the server returns http 403. No method of the controller is called.

Here is the part that most likely is the relevant information to solve this:

```
namespace webapi.Controllers
{
    [RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:Scopes")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Task.Test")]
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
    [Route("/")]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
```

I have read the documentation and the scenarios are both there but the problem is that they are not combined.

I have tried of many combinations but with no success. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

I took off the attributes [Authorize(Roles = "Task.Test")] and [Authohorize] from the class definition and then I added the policy to the method definition:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize("ThePolice")]
    [Route("dataaccess/livefeed")]
    public IActionResult GetData(int propertyId)
```

the code worked with both app roles and scopes worked.

The app roles and scopes can both be used in the same controller. That was clearly stated in a Youtube video Microsoft has published.

Here is what there is in the startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)               
      .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
      .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
      .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("ThePolice", policy =>
            {
                policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                string[] scps = new string[] { "access_as_user" };
                string[] roles = new string[] { "Task.Test" };                               
                policy.RequireScopeOrAppPermission(scps, roles);
            });
        });
```

Of course, the policy would work for the class definition also but I just made it like this first.